# Store data in redis session to enable automatic expiration when session expires

Tags: java, session, tomcat, redis

In our application, we were storing some data in HTTPSession. Now, we are using redis session manager. Is there a way to store our custom data in RedisSession instead of HTTPSession so that when redis session expires, our custom data is also removed automatically?

I am using tomcat-redis-session-manager (https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you are after, but I'll take a swing at it based on my reading of your question.

According to [the Readme](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager):

> The manager relies on the native expiration capability of Redis to
>   expire keys for automatic session expiration to avoid the overhead of
>   constantly searching the entire list of sessions for expired sessions

This means they pull the data from Redis rather than caching it in addition to Redis.

As to your "custom data", if you are storing this in the cache **only**, then when it expires it isn't available anymore. In the simplest reading of your question, this is what you are after.

There is no way to actually *remove the key from memory* as long as Redis has memory available. When the key is expired it no longer shows up in the list of keys and requests for the data held in the key will return the null value rather than the data that was stored there before the key expired. The best you could do is to set the data to an empty string when you are done with it.

If you are storing the data elsewhere and want to be notified the key has expired, that isn't possible given the framework, and even if it were I'd recommend refactoring that avoid the conflict condition that creates.

Now, technically you could talk directly to Redis and try to use the [Keyspace Notification](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) mechanism but at that point one would want to avoid the end-run and talk directly to Redis all the time. I am not sure it would even provide you with the notifications you'd be asking for in the latter case above.

Cheers,
Bill